# Is that right to write "Nightly Coyote"?

Tags: adjectives

I want to mean a coyote that frequently walks at night. Is it correct to write "Nightly Coyote"?

Comment: How frequently? **Every** night? My interpretation would be every night but [nightly](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/nightly) can mean *every* night also just *at* night. Welcome to ELU, by the way. You should include any research that you've done already and your full sentence in order to give context. Short questions like this are sometimes bumped to English Language Learners.

Comment: Thank you! And yes, I mean a coyote that walks just at night. The only research I've done was a google search that brought to me just a few mentions, thus I was curious in knowing if this term is correct.

Comment: Basic grammar: 'nightly' is an adverb which modifies verbs and adjectives, 'coyote' is a noun, which is modified by adjectives. So by simple labeling you can deduce that the two words do not fit naturally. 'Night Coyote' might be what you want (a coyote that is seen at night, also it's grammatical so not off-putting to native speakers).

Comment: @Mitch: “nightly” is also an adjective.  References: [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nightly), [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/nightly), [AHD](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=nightly), [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/nightly), [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/nightly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Nightly coyote" would not be understood without some explanation. Even then it sounds overly poetic, maybe romanticized.

A "nightly visitor" would be understood as someone who visits each night, similar to how "daily mail" is mail that arrives each day. A "nightly coyote" might be the name given to a specific coyote that is seen regularly each night.

"Nocturnal" is the word for an animal that is awake at night.

Comment: That's the point, I tried to make it sounds poetic, "a coyote that walks all night long looking for something".

Comment: Sure, it works poetically after an explanation. It suggests the coyote was named by someone else observing its patterns of behavior. The coyote would probably not think of himself as "nightly" that would be strange.

Comment: See, I agree with this answer - that's how I'd interpret it. And I'd probably think a nightly coyote would get old fast (somebody probably fed him and he keeps showing up!). But the definitions in [Collins and American Heritage](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/nightly) both list "happening at night" as well as "every night". I wonder if there's anything that can back up my (our) interpretation, or even if it's a regional thing?

Comment: I think a "Night Coyote" would be generically nocturnal (as opposed to a  "Day Coyote"). The OP says he is looking for a poetic interpretation… I'm not sure where to find examples to disambiguate.

Comment: Please read the definition from [Random House Kernerman Webster’s College Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/nightly). (2010): adj. 2 appearing or active at night. 3. of, pertaining to, or characteristic of night. Do you think it helps grant me a poetic license to write Nightly Coyote? By the way, thanks for your time and patience.

Comment: I am really sorry, just realized now that the "English Language Learners" @Pam mentioned above is another StackExchange community :o.

Comment: @NightlyCoyote you could use the discussion here to edit and expand your question (or even create a new one, linking to this one). I think you might have a valid question: there are two meanings of "nightly" and they seem quite distinct. Which is the more commonly accepted meaning, and how would the phrase "nightly coyote" be interpreted? There might be some adverb/adjective distinction or BrE vs AmE that other ELU users could help with.

Answer (score 0):

Adverbs can only be used to modify verbs, adjectives, and other adverbs. "Nightly" can be used to describe visitation or frequency, but not the "coyote" which is a noun.

Comment: Nightly is also an adjective.

Comment: @Laurel How is it also an adjective? 'The nightly train'?

Comment: @Mitch In the sense that every dictionary I checked lists an adjective sense ([example](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/nightly))? As an adjective it can be used in front of nouns so "nightly train" works.

Comment: @Laurel OK. Reading those examples, it makes sense. But it does allow me to modify my point. Adverbs, specifically time ones, will work with nouns that are _events_, but not well at all with objects. Only with a great semantic stretch might 'nightly' work with 'coyote', but on first (and second hearing) it is a real clunker.

Comment: How is this any different from a daily newspaper?